# How to get class from field?

Tags: java, class, reflection, field

I am trying to receive class field value via reflection. But when I call my code I receive  exception: IllegalArgumentException: Can not set *class* field *field* to java.lang.Class. (I am calling from javaagent)

My code:

```
 private static Class<?> GetInstance(Class<?> clz) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz1 = null;
    Field f = clz.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    clazz1 = f.get(clz).getClass();
    return clazz1;
}

private static Class GetClassLoader(Class<?> clz) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Field f = clz.getDeclaredField("classLoader");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Class cls = f.get(clz).getClass();
    return cls;
}

public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst){
    try{
        inst.addTransformer(new ClientTransfomer());

        Class<?> FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper = null;
        Class<?> InstanceClass;
        Class<?>[] classes = inst.getAllLoadedClasses();
        for(int i = 0;i < classes.length;i++){
            if(classes[i].getName().contains("cpw.mods.fml.common.asm.transformers.deobf.FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper")){
                FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper = classes[i];
            }

        }

        Class<?> instance = GetInstance(FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper);
        Class cloader = GetClassLoader(instance);

        Method m = cloader.getDeclaredMethod("findClass");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(null, "net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityClientPlayerMP");

    }catch (Exception e){


    }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For now I suspect that you may be looking for `f.getType()` but this will simply return type of reference (type of `classLoader` field which is always `RelaunchClassLoader`), not actual type of object which it holds.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get class from field?

With `fieldValue.getClass()`. Reflection not required.

Your code makes no sense.

- You have a method called `GetInstance()` which returns a `Class`, not an instance. You need to change the return value of this method to `Object` and remove the `getClass()` call inside it.
- You have a method called `GetClassLoader()` which returns a `Class`, not a `ClassLoader`. You need to change the return type of this method to `ClassLoader`, and remove the `getClass()` call inside it.
- You are then reflectively treating this object as though it *was* a `ClassLoader`, which it isn't, and trying to call `findClass()` on it.

But I can see no necessity for using a reflection at all here once you have the instance: you can just call `getClass().getClassLoader().findClass()` directly.

Comment: Well, `findClass` is `protected` so that would be a reason to use Reflection to invoke it, however, for most class loaders, using the `public` method `loadClass` instead would produce the same result. But here, to complete the list of things making no sense, `null` is passed as receiver instance to `m.invoke` instead of the object that is supposed to be a `ClassLoader`. And using `contains` to check for string equality looks strange, too.

Comment: @Holger The OP doesn't need to call `findClass().`. He should call `loadClass()`: use the public API. That's what it's for.

Comment: That’s what I said. There might be rare corner cases where a `ClassLoader` implementation doesn’t follow the standard delegation model, however, in this case, nothing in this code looks like being the result of such deep thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
    public class One {
        public Two two = new Two();
    }

    public class Two {
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        One one = new One();
        Class<?> clazz = one.getClass();
        try {
            Field twoField = clazz.getField("two");
            twoField.setAccessible(true);
            Class<?> twoClazz =Class.forName(twoField.getType().getName());

            Method method = twoClazz.getMethod("hello", null);

            method.invoke(twoClazz.newInstance(), null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a mistake in a code. Field not static. If I receive a class, I will need to call a public method from him.

Comment: It's strange, because i  execute code before sent. 
https://ideone.com/XUqCR7
i put two classes into main, but you can separate into files.

Answer (score 0):

Use getType() like below:

```
clz.getDeclaredField("fieldName").getType()
```